# How to create a 3d plot with vectors of unequal length?

Tags: matlab

How to create a 3d plot with vectors of unequal length? for example `x = [1:20]`, `y = [-10:5:10]` and `z` is a `20x5` matrix with different values. I am able to plot it using `surf` and `mesh`. but `surf` and `mesh` represents continuous data. these functions connect the discrete data. I want to represent this data in 3d as discrete, like `stem()` plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, can you not simply do:

```
stem3(x,y,z)
```

Update: you need to make sure that `x`, `y` and `z` are of the same size though...

Comment: Thanks. I somehow arrived to stem but did not know there is stem3 too. Got the answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: Excellent. Can you accept the answer if it helped you answer your question?